# How can I disable a ComboBox item if the selected value is only relevant to a certain option?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have 4 combo boxes on my windows form.

ComboBox1 has 2 items which are "STUDENT" and "PERSONNEL".

If the user selected "PERSONNEL" on ComboBox1, ComboBox2 to ComboBox4 would be disabled. But if the user changed it to "STUDENT", ComboBox2 to ComboBox4 is enabled again.

I tried an if statement:

```
If cbSORP.SelectedItem Is "PERSONNEL" Then
        cbCourse.Enabled = False
        cbYear.Enabled = False
        cbSection.Enabled = False
    Else
        cbCourse.Enabled = True
        cbYear.Enabled = True
        cbSection.Enabled = True
    End If
```

I also tried putting it in a panel and using a timer but still no luck. I'm still learning so please go easy on me.

Comment: `SelectedItem` is an Object Type, so you can have something like: `if cbSORP.SelectedItem?.ToString() = "PERSONNEL" then ...` in `SelectionChangeCommitted`, don't use a Timer here. IF the items in your ComboBox are actually strings. If this is not the case, then you have to cast `SelectedItem` to the actual Type.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since I programmed in VB, but if I recall correctly, the `Is` operator tells you whether two variables refer to the exact same object (i.e. they point to the same memory). It does not compare the *values* of two variables. Change `Is` to `=` and it should work fine:

```
If cbSORP.SelectedItem = "PERSONNEL" Then    ' <-- changed comparison operator
    cbCourse.Enabled = False
    cbYear.Enabled = False
    cbSection.Enabled = False
Else
    cbCourse.Enabled = True
    cbYear.Enabled = True
    cbSection.Enabled = True
End If
```

See [help on `Is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/is-operator) (to see why something that *sounds* right won't work here) and [help on comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators) for using `=` and friends in Visual Basic.

Best of luck, and don't give up! Everyone was a learner.

Comment: I tried changing the operator to "IS" and it's still not working. But I'll keep trying. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `Is` operator was part of the problem. Have a look at the comment that the user @Jimi made after your question. It looks helpful, especially the `cbSORP.SelectedItem?.ToString() = "PERSONNEL"` condition. Please let me know if that works, and I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ComboBox's `Text` property instead of `SelectedItem` property in `SelectedIndexChanged` event of ComboBox,

```
Private Sub cbSORP_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   If cbSORP.Text = "PERSONNEL" Then
       cbCourse.Enabled = False
       cbYear.Enabled = False
       cbSection.Enabled = False
   ElseIf cbSORP.Text = "STUDENT" Then
       cbCourse.Enabled = True
       cbYear.Enabled = True
       cbSection.Enabled = True
   End If
End Sub
```